# How can I overwrite a hook from a theme

Tags: 8, hooks

I have a custom sub-theme of the Seven theme. The Seven theme makes some node alteration via `seven_form_node_form_alter()`. I would like to have `seven_form_node_form_alter()` not run at all or I would like to overwrite it.  How can I accomplish this?

I tried `hook_module_implements_alter()` but there was no implementation of Seven in there. (I'm wondering if that only works with modules.)
Another thought was `hook_theme_registry_alter()` but I couldn't see anything there about form alters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hook_module_implements_alter()` allows just to alter the hooks implemented by modules, and `hook_theme_registry_alter()` alters only the theme functions, not hooks.

If you look at the code of [`drupal_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/drupal_alter/7.x), the function that invokes all the alter hooks, you will see the following code, which deals with alter hooks implemented by themes.

```
// Allow the theme to alter variables after the theme system has been
// initialized.
global $theme, $base_theme_info;
if (isset($theme)) {
  $theme_keys = array();
  foreach ($base_theme_info as $base) {
    $theme_keys[] = $base->name;
  }
  $theme_keys[] = $theme;
  foreach ($theme_keys as $theme_key) {
    $function = $theme_key . '_' . $hook;
    if (function_exists($function)) {
      $functions[$cid][] = $function;
    }
    if (isset($extra_types)) {
      foreach ($extra_types as $extra_type) {
        $function = $theme_key . '_' . $extra_type . '_alter';
        if (function_exists($function)) {
          $functions[$cid][] = $function;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The alter hooks implemented by the base themes run first; if you have a sub-theme, and that is the current theme, its alter hook will run last. The only thing I see you could do is (in the implementation of the same hook done from your theme) to remove the changes introduced by `seven_form_node_form_alter()` that you don't want in your theme.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late for answering this but the solution is:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
 $form['#after_build'][] = '_mymodule_after_build';
}


/**
 * Form #after_build callback for hook_form_alter().
 */
function _mymodule_after_build(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['#theme'] = ['my_own_template'];
  return $form;
}
```